# javascript regex error

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, expression, opera

I have this string:

```
£1,134.00 (£1,360.80 inc VAT)
```

And I am trying to extract the numbers to get the following:

```
['1,134.00','1,360.80']
```

Using the following regex pattern in Javascript:

```
/\d*,?\d+\.\d{2}/g
```

It is working fine in Chrome, but I get this error in Opera:

```
Uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (£1,360.80 inc VAT)
Error thrown at line 75, column 784 in <anonymous function: k.error>(g) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js:
    throw"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "+g;
```

Obviously I would like it to work in all modern browsers but I have no idea what is causing this. I have also tried several other regex patterns and have looked into escape characters as I thought it might be that.

Any ideas?!

Let me know if more info is needed. Thanks

Comment: What the the whole code you are using? Obviously you have jQuery in it somewhere but right now you have shown no jQuery.

Comment: indeed - it would be interesting to see the full code, because this error must occur somewhere else..

Comment: Best way would be to set up a jsFiddle that demoes your problem. Or at least edit the relevant parts of your into the question, not just the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*unrecognized expression: (£1,360.80 inc VAT)*  <= that's not an error in your regex.  Your string is not being a string. Somehow it's getting mixed and interpreted as part of your javascript.